# Motivation for proving any nontrivial normal subgroup of $A_5$ has a 3-cycle?

Tags: group-theory

This question is taken from M.A. Armstrong's book *Groups & Symmetry*. Question 15.12.

This aim of this problem is to introduce the concept of a simple group. It asks us to first work out the commutators (whose products I've provided)$$(12345)^{-1}(345)^{-1}(12345)(345)=(245),$$ $$(12)(34)(345)^{-1}(12)(34)(345)=(354).$$

The next part of the question asks us to show that any non-trivial normal subgroup of $A_5$ must contain a 3-cycle. From here I am able to conclude (from a previous problem) that this normal subgroup must be all of $A_5$ (because if it contains one 3-cycle it must contain all, and the 3-cycles generate $A_5$), and hence prove $A_5$ is simple.

Can somebody help me understand if the two calculations above are meant to act as motivation for the proof that every non-trivial normal subgroup of $A_5$ contains a 3-cycle? If not, does it serve a purpose?

Comment: The above calculations (once generalized suitably) show that any normal subgroup must contains a 3-cycle if it contains either a 5-cycle or  product of two disjoint 2-cycles.

Comment: But why state it like that and not as a conjugate $(345)^{-1}(12345)(345)$ and $(345)^{-1}(12)(34)(345)$?

Comment: Because those are not 3-cycles.

Comment: But isn't a normal subgroup made up of conjugates and not commutators?

Comment: Being normal means that it contains all conjugates of its elements. But this implies that it contains all commutators $[a,b]$ as long as at least one of $a$ or $b$ is in the subgroup.

Comment: Just to add to @TobiasKildetoft comment, $a^b = a [a, b]$.